# Retrieve all relevant values from a nested HashMap with the same outermap key

Tags: java

I have a Map where the value is also a Map:

```
HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> map;
```

I have populated it so that the values are something like:

```
"Red"="Apple",10
"Red"="Cherry",5
"Red"="Strawberry",7
"Yellow"="Banana",12
"Orange"="Orange",9
```

I basically want to be able to pass in `Red` and retrieve all the relevant keys of the nested map (`Apple`, `Cherry`, `Strawberry`). When I use the following code it seems to only return one value instead of all:

```
public class Groceries {

    private HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> groceries;

    public Groceries() {
        groceries = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Set<String> getFruitsGivenColor(String color) {
        Set<String> fruits = new HashSet<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = groceries.get(origin);
        for (HashMap.Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            fruits.add(entry.getKey());
        }
        return fruits;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just get the keys of the nested map?

```
String key = "Red";
Set<String> keys = groceries.get(key).keySet();   //this is what you want
```

Also, it sounds like you may be `put`ting several pairs into the map with the same key for each, and thus are overriding the previous `put` calls, yielding a total of one element. If you are doing something like:

```
map.put("Red", appleMap);
map.put("Red", cherryMap);
map.put("Red", strawberryMap);
```

You should be instead doing:

```
map.put("Red", appleMap);

for (String key : cherryMap)
{
    map.get("Red").put(cherryMap.get("Red"));
}

for (String key : strawberryMap)
{
    map.get("Red").put(strawberryMap("Red"));
}
```